# Converting pandas dataframe into dictionary where keys are index and values are list of column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe

df:

```
    cola    colb   colc   cold
0      0    'a'     'b'   'c'
1      1    'd'     None  None
2      2    'g'     'h'   None
```

I want to convert it into `dict` where index are keys and list of column values are values like below:

```
d = {0 : [0,'a','b','c'], 1: [1,'d'], 2: [2,'g','h'] }
```

**What I tried**:

```
df.to_dict(orient='index')
```

I also tried with other values in `orient` parameters but nothing worked.

**EDIT**:

I want to ignore the NULL values in dictionary like shown in output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='list'`, only before transpose `DataFrame`:

```
d = df.T.to_dict(orient='list')
print (d)
{0: [0, 'a', 'b', 'c'], 1: [1, 'd', 'e', 'f'], 2: [2, 'g', 'h', 'i']}
```

EDIT:

```
d = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{0: [0, 'a', 'b', 'c'], 1: [1, 'd'], 2: [2, 'g', 'h']}
```

Or:

```
d = {k:[x for x in v if x is not None] for k, v in df.T.to_dict(orient='list').items()}
print (d)
{0: [0, 'a', 'b', 'c'], 1: [1, 'd'], 2: [2, 'g', 'h']}
```

Comment: the edit version worked for me, i don't believe `to_dict(orient='list')` will give the desired result